# Angular: Get value from mat select based id

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am creating a dynamic form with multiple dropdowns (mat-select). The value for the select is the key. After the user has selected all dropdowns I want the selected values to be shown. However, as the select only holds the key and not the value, I am confused how I show achieve my goal.

**Option 1** - Use id as value binding

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" class="w-75">
      <mat-label>{{question.label}}</mat-label>
      <mat-select [formControlName]="question.key">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of question.options" [value]="opt.key">
          {{opt.value}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
      <mat-error *ngIf="!isValid">
        {{question.label}} is required
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
```

**Option 2** - Use object as value binding**

I tried earlier to bind the value of the option to be the object itself (opt), that fixed my issue. But instead I was not able to set a default value. In this case I tested with both [value] and [ngValue] without success, example below:

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" class="w-75">
      <mat-label>{{question.label}}</mat-label>
      <mat-select [formControlName]="question.key">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of question.options" [value]="opt">
          {{opt.value}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
      <mat-error *ngIf="!isValid">
        {{question.label}} is required
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Generates the dropdown just fine. In the case that I want to set the default value, the value is not being selected but it outputs that it is selected as it should..

```
    let testOption = {key: 17, value: "Country 17"};
    this.form.controls.country.setValue(testOption); //Updates not visible in mat-select
    console.log(this.form.controls.country.value); //Output shows {key: 17, value: "Country 17"}
```

Any tips on how to solve any of the two options? I really would like to avoid to write a generic function that the html calls for to get the value. (Like in ts doing Array.filter....)

Thanks!

Comment: Use the object as the value but supply a function to the 'compareWith' input for mat-select.

Comment: Hi @robbieAreBest! I have actually tried that without luck. Any suggestion how to implement it?

Comment: I've added a more thorough explanation as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a compare function for your option objects:

```
  compareOptions(option1: Option, option2: Option) {
    return option1.key === option2.key;
  }
```

Then supply this function to mat-select:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="w-75">
    <mat-label>Question</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="question" [compareWith]="compareOptions">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt">
        {{opt.value}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Then, set the form value and the new object will be compared by your id 'key' instead:

```
this.form.get('question')?.setValue({key: 3, value: 'Country 3'});
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqvgfk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.ts

---

Alternatively, you could find the option in the array using the ID and set the form control value to that. Since it is the same object reference, you will not need a compare function:

```
 this.form.get('question')?.setValue(this.options.find(opt => opt.key === 3));
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqvgfk-ymkixm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.ts

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to add default value to select itself. Note that you are binding default value to parent mat-select element.

```
 <mat-select [value]="defaultOpt" formControlName="question.key">
           <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of question.options" [value]="opt">
            {{opt.value}}
           </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```

This way, you can set both a default value, and receive the input you want.

Comment: Hi @usalin! How do you mean I should set the default value now? Remember the mat-select is created in a *ngFor, so it will create about 10 dropdowns

Comment: defaultOpt is a separate concern from the value you pass to *ngFor - question.options.  Number of select for that control will still be the same - only 1 select item will be created. Nested mat-options can be 10 or more.

Comment: You should pass a single default option object to defaultOpt - with a key and value you want - not a list of options as in the *ngFor directive. If you want you can make it more generic like passing question.options[0] .

Comment: No, I think you missed that I have a div outside this for ngFor to add multiple drop downs (mat-select). By this, I cannot have one variable static “defaultOpt” as it will change all my different drop downs. For example one drop down is for country, one for gender, etc..

Comment: Is it possible to add a  default or chosen property to question object?